# Ruby on Rails 2.3.8: How do I set up my unit tests such that when there is an error, I can have all the variables in the current scope printed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, testing

Let's say I'm in a for loop, and something in the for loop breaks.

How would I set up some sort of exception catching so that when my testing fails, all variables visible to the current scope, including loop index, are printed to the console?

Maybe there is a way to change the method that ruby uses to output all the error text to the console? and include all the variable currently in scope?

Answer (score 0):

Although you can iterate over `@@class` and `@instance` variables, as far as I know the regular Ruby interpreters do not allow you to show all local, scoped variables. These are really just constructs in the parse tree and are not preserved when they fall out of scope. Further, you may have multiple local variables with the same name, but only the top-most one will be visible at any given time.

You might have to define your own `rescue` handler that dumps out any variables you've tagged as being interested in. Either that or experiment with using the Ruby debugger.

An alternative is something like this:

```
def clear_capture!
  @captured = nil
end

def capture(*args)
  (@captured ||= { }).merge(args)
end

def dump_capture
  puts @capture.inspect
end
```

In your tests you'd do something like this:

```
  def setup
    clear_captured!
  end

  def test_something
    foo = :foo
    bar = 12

    capture(:foo => foo, :bar => bar)

    # ...

    capture(:foo => foo, :other => other)

  rescue
    report_capture
  end
```

You could enhance this to use `eval` which would make the syntax tighter.

Comment: that seems to me like more of a glorified begin-rescue \=

Comment: That's what you're asking for, though. If you want to catch exceptions, `rescue` is the facility you use.